# What is the total amount of public IPv4 addresses?

Tags: ip-address, ipv4

Yes, I am needing to know what the total number possible IPs in the public IPv4 space.

I'm not sure where to even get a neat list of all the IP address ranges, so could someone point me to a resource to calculate this myself or calculate the total number of IPs for me?

Also, by Public IPs I mean not counting reserved or private-range IP addresses.. Only the ones that can be access through the internet.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

According to [Reserved IP addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses) there are 588,514,304 reserved addresses and since there are 4,294,967,296 (2^32) IPv4 addressess in total, there are **3,706,452,992** public addresses.

And too many *addresses* in this post.

Comment: Ipv4 addresses address the addressing problem, but nobody addresses the /addresses/ problem.

Comment: This has been since updated to 592, 708, 864 reserved addresses due to RFC 6598, resulting in 3,702,258,432 public addresses

Comment: you said there are 4,294,967,296 "IP addressess ... in total" ... rather, there are 4,294,967,296 "possible combinations."  2^32 is correct per multiplication rule, answer correct, just used the slang description.  "IP addresses" refers to possible and existing addresses, not just mathematical combinations that are theoretically possible.  unless I am wrong?  aren't some banned?  (see below) @Marko

Comment: Here is a point to ponder: 16 million of these addresses are allocated to the loopback. That is, we have 16 million ways to address localhost. Starting from 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2 and up to 127.255.255.254. I've been googling trying to find why, and so far I have not read a compelling use case for this phenomenal waste!

Comment: @ifelsemonkey I have `127.0.0.1`, `127.0.0.2`, `127.0.0.3`, and sometimes `127.0.0.4` in use on my debian box, various web servers all listening on the same ports. I think it also uses `127.0.1.1` for something.

Comment: we have to remove some, because of sub-netting. Each subnet looses 2 addresses.

Comment: Please edit your post to write out the numbers phonetically

Comment: IPv6 solves the limited addressing problem by adding more addresses to the address space, resulting in more addresses overall. This addresses your address size question.

Answer (score 36):

https://www.ripe.net/internet-coordination/press-centre/understanding-ip-addressing

> For IPv4, this pool is 32-bits (2³²) in size and contains 4,294,967,296 IPv4 addresses.

In case of IPv6

> The IPv6 address space is 128-bits (2¹²⁸) in size, containing 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,456 IPv6 addresses.

***inclusive of RESERVED IP***

```
 Reserved address blocks
 Range  Description Reference

 0.0.0.0/8  Current network (only valid as source address)  RFC 6890
 10.0.0.0/8 Private network RFC 1918
 100.64.0.0/10  Shared Address Space    RFC 6598
 127.0.0.0/8    Loopback    RFC 6890
 169.254.0.0/16 Link-local  RFC 3927
 172.16.0.0/12  Private network RFC 1918
 192.0.0.0/24   IETF Protocol Assignments   RFC 6890
 192.0.2.0/24   TEST-NET-1, documentation and examples  RFC 5737
 192.88.99.0/24 IPv6 to IPv4 relay (includes 2002::/16) RFC 3068
 192.168.0.0/16 Private network RFC 1918
 198.18.0.0/15  Network benchmark tests RFC 2544
 198.51.100.0/24    TEST-NET-2, documentation and examples  RFC 5737
 203.0.113.0/24 TEST-NET-3, documentation and examples  RFC 5737
 224.0.0.0/4    IP multicast (former Class D network)   RFC 5771
 240.0.0.0/4    Reserved (former Class E network)   RFC 1700
 255.255.255.255    Broadcast   RFC 919
```

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Special-use_addresses) has full details
and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address) has details of IPv6.

Comment: Upvote for adding interesting note on IPv6, removed upvote for not addressing OP question regarding number of reserved IPs.

Comment: Upvote for adding interesting note on IPv6. Useful answer, thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Just a small correction for Marko's answer: exact number can't be produced out of some general calculations straight forward due to the next fact:
Valid IP addresses should also not end with binary 0 or 1 sequences that have same length as zero sequence in subnet mask. So the final answer really depends on the total number of subnets (Marko's answer - 2 * total subnet count).

Comment: From anonymous: Actually Marko's answer was correct for the question asked. You are answering a question which was not asked. The original question did not mention valid IP addresses. Addresses ending in 0 are valid addresses for a Network address. Addresses ending in 1 are valid host address. Addresses ending in 255 are valid broadcast addresses but not valid host address. You will be surprised that while most TCP/IP implementation will throw up an error if you try to add a broadcast or network address to IP host, there is at one vendor who will let you do it. I never figured out why.

Comment: addresses that end in 255 are not always valid broadcast addresses, also host addresses can end in 255. It all depends on your network mask

Comment: @AndriyK “Also, by Public IPs I mean not counting reserved…Only the ones that can be access through the internet. ” so this answer is correct.

Comment: This is totally wrong. There's no requirement for a public network to even have a network or a broadcast address. I've successfully run services on a .0 of a public IPv4 network.

Answer (score 3):

## Public IP Addresses

> https://github.com/stephenlb/geo-ip will generate a list of Valid IP Public Addresses including Localities.

**`'1.0.0.0/8'` to `'191.0.0.0/8'`** are the valid public IP Address range exclusive of the reserved Private IP Addresses as follows:

```py
import iptools
## Private IP Addresses
private_ips = iptools.IpRangeList(
    '0.0.0.0/8',      '10.0.0.0/8',     '100.64.0.0/10', '127.0.0.0/8',
    '169.254.0.0/16', '172.16.0.0/12',  '192.0.0.0/24',  '192.0.2.0/24',
    '192.88.99.0/24', '192.168.0.0/16', '198.18.0.0/15', '198.51.100.0/24',
    '203.0.113.0/24', '224.0.0.0/4',    '240.0.0.0/4',   '255.255.255.255/32'
)
```

## IP Generator

Generates a JSON dump of IP Addresses and associated Geo information.
Note that the valid public IP Address range is
from `'1.0.0.0/8'` to `'191.0.0.0/8'` excluding the reserved
Private IP Address ranges shown lower down in this readme.

```sh
docker build -t geo-ip .
docker run -e IPRANGE='54.0.0.0/30' geo-ip               ## a few IPs
docker run -e IPRANGE='54.0.0.0/26' geo-ip               ## a few more IPs
docker run -e IPRANGE='54.0.0.0/16' geo-ip               ## a lot more IPs
docker run -e IPRANGE='0.0.0.0/0'   geo-ip               ## ALL IPs ( slooooowwwwww )
docker run -e IPRANGE='0.0.0.0/0'   geo-ip > geo-ip.json ## ALL IPs saved to JSON File
docker run geo-ip
```

A little faster option for scanning all valid public addresses:

```sh
for i in $(seq 1 191); do \
    docker run -e IPRANGE="$i.0.0.0/8" geo-ip; \
    sleep 1; \ 
done
```

This prints less than *4,228,250,625* JSON lines to STDOUT.
Here is an example of one of the lines:

```
{"city": "Palo Alto", "ip": "0.0.0.0", "longitude": -122.1274,
 "continent": "North America", "continent_code": "NA",
 "state": "California", "country": "United States", "latitude": 37.418,
 "iso_code": "US", "state_code": "CA", "aso": "PubNub",
 "asn": "11404", "zip_code": "94107"}
```

### Private and Reserved IP Range

The dockerfile in the repo above will exclude non-usable IP addresses
following the guide from the wikipedia article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses

### MaxMind Geo IP

The dockerfile imports a free public Database provided by https://www.maxmind.com/en/home

Comment: Please put explicit disclaimers on your own project links; *disclaimer: this is a project I created* or similar.

Comment: You know there are quite a lot of valid public IP addresses above 191.0.0.0/8. 195.0.0.1 for example.

Answer (score 1):

3.681 billion is the current total in the year 2020.

Source: https://blog.apnic.net/2020/01/21/addressing-2019/