# Why IPv4 address is in bytes and can not be in integer range?

Tags: java, ipv4

I am new to java and networking, when writing Java socket program I discovered that, **IPv4** address can have maximum value of `255.255.255.255`

Also, 255 is the maximum value of Byte.

My doubt is why, Integer range is(can be) not used for more(like, `23467.28321.1784.58256`) **IPv4** address?

Comment: Because that's the way the spec was written.

Comment: Because coding it on 4 bytes seemed enough at the time.

Comment: IPv4 addresses consist of 4 '8 bit' octets. So it was, and so it shall ever be.

Comment: what you're mentioning is somewhat like IPv6 - 8 blocks of 16bit words. In the (VERY) far future this will be extended to blocks of 32bit, probably - but by then even the kids of our kids will be long gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IPv4 uses **32-bit (four-byte) addresses**, which limits the address space to 4228250626 (232) addresses.

4 bytes mean 32 bits so, each byte can have 8 bits and maximum value of 8 bits number is 255. (11111111 in binary is equal to 255 in decimal). Therefore, `255.255.255.255` is maximum range of IPv4.

And reason for this limitation could be, at that time not much IPv4 addresses were required so, specs were designed this way. :)

Comment: the actual, maximum amount of permutations is 4228250625 --> 255^4, 255 permutations per segment, 4 segments in total and IPv4 is not "legacy". Its the worldwide standard - which is BEING replaced by IPv6 in the NEXT DECADES OR SO, it will take a lot of time to replace strictly IPv4 - hardware with never models in data centres

Comment: By legacy I meant it was developed when not much addresses were required, may be its conveying wrong meaning. I will remove it. :)

Comment: @specializt : It's not 255^4. The amount of available addresses is 256^4 = 4294967296. You must have missed that zero is included.

Comment: zero is not a valid address - its reserved. You will not find a single IP on this planet which has the value 0 in either the last or first segment - even the two segments in-between are always reserved. Apparently this is even included in the standard : RFC1122 and beyond.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for the info, but it seems that both of us were wrong :D There are only 3,706,452,992 addresses. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437169/what-is-the-total-amount-of-public-ipv4-addresses

Comment: There are 2^32 = 256^4 = 4294967296 IPv4 addresses. Some of them have special meaning (like 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255), are used for multicast (224.0.0.0/4), are reserved (240.0.0.0/4) etc. Take a look at http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/. Since we stopped using classful addressing  (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4632) `0`s in addresses are nothing special. For example `192.168.0.0/23` contains `192.168.0.0` to `192.168.1.255`. The first one is the network address, the last one is the broadcast address, but e.g. `192.168.1.0` is a perfectly valid address for a node to use.

Answer (score 3):

The dotted notation (`abc.def.geh.ijk`) is merely a human-readable way of expressing the value of four octets (bytes). All IPv4 addresses are four octets long, as defined in [RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#section-2.3):

> Addresses are fixed length of four octets (32 bits).

Each group of digits contains the decimal value of a byte, thus limiting the values to 0 - 255. Values larger than 255 cannot be mapped to a byte and are thus are not valid for an IPv4 address.